# C# override base class property in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a question on generic class and inheritance in C#. Maybe I'm wrong somewhere and such code design is not following the best practices but I really hope to make it work. I have the following class structure:

```
public class BaseInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseData
{
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public BaseData Data { get; protected set; }
    public BaseInfo Info { get; protected set; }
}

public class SomeClass<TData, TInfo> : SomeClass
    where TData : BaseData, new()
    where TInfo : BaseInfo, new()
{
    public new TData Data { get; protected set; }
    public new TInfo Info { get; protected set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        Data = new TData();
        Info = new TInfo();
    }
}
```

And then I specified a specific class:

```
public class SpecificInfo : BaseInfo
{
    public int MaxNumber { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificData : BaseData
{
    public int StartFrom { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificClass : SomeClass<SpecificData, SpecificInfo>
{
    public SpecificClass(int startFrom, int maxNumber)
    {
        Data = new SpecificData
        {
            StartFrom = startFrom
        };

        Info = new SpecificInfo
        {
            Id = 1,
            MaxNumber = maxNumber
        };
    }
}
```

Then I want to use it in my program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var specific = new SpecificClass(100, 1000);

        Process(specific);
    }

    static void Process(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        var data = someClass.Data;

        if (data is SpecificData specificData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"This is specific data {specificData.StartFrom}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is not specific data, sorry");
        }
    }
}
```

But it shows that the data is not `SpecificData`. I guess that it's not working because `SomeClass.Data` is added with the `new` keyword so there are two `Data` properties in the `specific` object. Is it possible to rewrite this code to save base non generic class as an argument of `Process(SomeClass someClass)` method and save the rest of class structure with some modifications but make it workable? Maybe I can find the needed `Data` inside of the `Process` method?
Thank you!

Comment: "*I guess that it's not working because SomeClass.Data is added with the new keyword so there are two Data properties in the specific object.*" -- correct

Comment: @canton7, can the same behavior be achieved with interface instead of a base class? So that I will pass `ISomeClass` to `Process()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around this by using an interface instead of a base class, and using explicit interface implementation to implement the interface's properties:

```
public interface ISomeClass
{
    BaseData Data { get; }
    BaseInfo Info { get; }
}

public class SomeClass<TData, TInfo> : ISomeClass
    where TData : BaseData, new()
    where TInfo : BaseInfo, new()
{
    public TData Data { get; protected set; }
    BaseData ISomeClass.Data => Data;
        
    public TInfo Info { get; protected set; }
    BaseInfo ISomeClass.Info => Info;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        Data = new TData();
        Info = new TInfo();
    }
}
```

---

If you're using C# 9, you can also make use of return type covariance:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract BaseData Data { get; }
    public abstract BaseInfo Info { get; }
}

public class SomeClass<TData, TInfo> : BaseClass
    where TData : BaseData, new()
    where TInfo : BaseInfo, new()
{
    public override TData Data { get; }
    public override TInfo Info { get; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        Data = new TData();
        Info = new TInfo();
    }
}
```

Note that I had to make the properties in `SomeClass` getter-only, as the base property needs to be getter-only, and you can't add a `set` accessor in an override.

If you do need to set this property outside of the constructor, you can do something like:

```
public class SomeClass<TData, TInfo> : BaseClass
    where TData : BaseData, new()
    where TInfo : BaseInfo, new()
{
    protected TData MutableData { get; set; }
    public override TData Data => MutableData;
    
    protected TInfo MutableInfo { get; set; }
    public override TInfo Info => MutableInfo;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        MutableData = new TData();
        MutableInfo = new TInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not using c# 9 so I selected the first suggestion and it's working with a little modification of my code

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with SpecificClass

```
static void Process(SomeClass someClass)
{
    if (someClass is SpecificClass specificClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"This is specific data {specificClass.Data.StartFrom}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is not specific data, sorry");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working but the second answer is more suitable for my needs. Sorry